# Equivalence of definitions of Noetherian Ring, another proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, then the following are equivalent

-1. Every ideal in $R$ is finitely generated

-3. Every nonempty collection of ideals of $R$ has a maximal element

I will also mention

-2. Every ascending chain of ideals in $A$ is stationary

which is also equivalent to 1 and 3.

---

I have proved $1\Rightarrow 3$ like this:

Let's suppose every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated and let $F$ be a nonempty family of ideals which does not have a maximal element. Let $I_1\in F$. As $I_1$ is not maximal there exists a $I_2\in F$ such that $I_1\subset I_2$. As $I_2$ is not maximal there exists $I_3$ such that...

And so we made the strictly ascending chain:
$$I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \cdots$$
(Which clearly contradicts 2, but I will continue as if I didn't knew 2.)

Let's consider the ideal
$$I=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty I_n$$
We know that $I$ is finitely generated, so $I=\langle x_1,\cdots,x_m\rangle$. We can easily note tht there exists some $n$ such that $x_1,\cdots,x_m\in I_n$, so $I_n=I$ which is a contradiction since the chain is not stationary.

---

I want to prove it ($1\Rightarrow 3$) in another way, without building an ascending chain of ideals, and without assuming 2.

Something like

> Let's suppose every ideal in $R$ is finitely generated, and let $F$ be a nonempty family of ideals, and so ... ... ... $M$ is a maximal element of $F$.

Or

> Let $F$ be a nonempty family of ideals which does not have a maximal element, and so ... ... (Not building ascending chains) ... ... we get a contradiction.

Is there any way to do it?

Note: I know I'm using some choice in the proof, I've no problem with that.

Note2: I usually see the proof of the equivalence as $1\Rightarrow 2\Rightarrow 3 \Rightarrow 1$, but I've found some proofs of $2\Rightarrow 1$, or $3\Rightarrow  2$ interesting, too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that which I wanted to find is another proof or $1\Rightarrow 3$.

Comment: I don't think that what you're asking for is likely to be possible.  One way or another, we need to apply Zorn's lemma (this implication is not decidable in ZF), and we have to pick out a maximal element, which requires verifying the chain condition.  The only way around this would be to radically transform the problem by constructing some _other_ big poset, or some way of applying choice or the well-ordering principle, and then translating it all back into your conclusion about this poset of ideals.  But I would think that such an approach would be equivalent to just using Zorn directly.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. If you could explain why you object to a proof that considers an ascending chain of ideals, it might be possible to help.

Comment: I don't object, I just wanted to find another proof... This way I think I'm going $1\Rightarrow 2\Rightarrow 3$, instead of $1\Rightarrow 3$ directly. I mean, I can prove the equivalence between 2 and 3 without even thinking about the generating sets. But to prove the equivalence between 1 and 3 it seems I will need to use ascending chains.